# Find the interval of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(np)!(x^n)}{(n!)^p}$ where p is a natural number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I tried to use the ratio test to find the radius of convergence of this power series and evaluated $R$ to be the following:
            $$R=\frac{1}{p^p}.$$
This would imply that the series converges absolutely in the interval ($\frac{-1}{p^p}$,$\frac{1}{p^p}$).
I then put $x=\frac{-1}{p^p}$ to test the convergence at the endpoints.
This would result into the following series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(np)!}{(n!)^p\cdot p^{np}}.$$
I then tried to use the absolute convergence test and tried to test the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(np)!}{(n!)^p\cdot p^{np}}.$$
I know that this series diverges for $p=1$ because when p=1, the series becomes $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty1$$ and this series diverges as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$$ which is not zero and thus by nth term test the series diverges for p=1.
However I cannot think of a way to show in general that this series diverges for any natural number $p$. I tried to use the ratio test but this results in $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$=1 and thus the test fails. As I have not been taught the Raabe's test or Stirling formula, I am looking for a solution that does not use these concepts.

Comment: Try using Stirling's formula.

Comment: If $p \ge 1$, show $\frac{(np)!}{(n!)^p\cdot p^p}$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: @GEdgar : As did I.  It is the *first* test anyone should apply to an unfamiliar series.

Comment: I am sorry but I had made an algebraic error.The series at the endpoint was supposed to have a p^(np) and due to the n involved I am not able to prove that it does not tend to zero

Comment: @Gary : we have not been taught the Stirling formula